# filter report based on date

Tags: vba, ms-access, filter, ms-access-2016

I have a table with date column a query for the same table and a report, on my form I have a button which loads the report using vba code which is below, I have two text fields to filter date on the report, my issue is with the date it is not being filtered. my code is below

```
Public Function makeMWO_RPT(Optional excelMode As Boolean = False)

    Dim ctlArr(3) As String
    ctlArr(0) = "Combo79"
    ctlArr(1) = "Combo82"
    ctlArr(2) = "WOPRCO"
    ctlArr(3) = "Combo165"
    
    Dim fldArr(3) As String
    fldArr(0) = "[Group]"
    fldArr(1) = "[User status]"
    fldArr(2) = "[Priority]"
    fldArr(3) = "iif([orders].[User status] In (""Closed"",""Open""),""YES"",""NO"")"
    
        'for date -- for date -- for date -- for date -- for date
    Dim qDef, sqlStr, frm As Form
    Set frm = Forms("Statusfrm")
    Set qDef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("OrderNewQry")
    sqlStr = "SELECT orders.[Group], orders.Order, orders.Description,orders.Post_Form, orders.Attachment, orders.Video_link, orders.[Estimated costs], orders.[Total], orders.Location, orders.[System status], orders.Priority, orders.date, orders.[User status], " & _
"orders.Equipment, orders.Diff, orders.Remarks,[orders].[User status] In (""Closed *"",""Open *"") AS Completed
"FROM orders"

  Dim filtrStr As String
    If Not IsNull(frm("Text489")) Then
        filtrStr = "[date] >= #" & frm("Text489") & "#"
    End If
    
    If Not IsNull(frm("Text491")) Then
        filtrStr = filtrStr & " AND [date] <= #" & frm("Text491") & "#"
    End If
    
    If filtrStr <> "" Then
        sqlStr = sqlStr & " WHERE " & filtrStr
    End If
    
    qDef.SQL = sqlStr
     'for date -- for date -- for date -- for date -- for date
     
     
    Dim baseSQL, qName, rName
    


    baseSQL = "SELECT orders.[Group], orders.Order, orders.Description,orders.Post_Form, orders.Attachment, orders.Video_link, orders.[Estimated costs], orders.[Total], orders.Location, orders.[System status], orders.Priority, orders.date, orders.[User status], " & _
"orders.Equipment, orders.Diff, orders.Remarks,[orders].[User status] In (""Closed *"",""Open *"") AS Completed
"FROM orders"


     
    
    qName = "OrderNewQry"
    rName = "FUllOpenOrdersRpt"
    
    makeGenericRPT ctlArr, fldArr, baseSQL, qName, rName, excelMode
    
End Function
```

Comment: Does the query SQL really change so much that you need to modify object as opposed to just applying filter to report? Are you using international date structure?

Comment: the query works fine for the other filtrations, except the date it is not filtering it if I selected date.

Comment: Did not answer my question.

Comment: Since everything else is working it might be a date format issue, but I can't tell from the code.  For instance, if you are depending on sorting by exact time then look for a truncation issue like a date textbox or date table column whose format is set to short date.  If you are sorting by date only, make sure to adjust the query to ignore time information if your dates have times.  A very rare case is when the dates are stored in a date format that is unusual in your part of the world and you don't catch any conversion errors.  Like getting us format date strings in europe.